# Error in next auth for type GET and POST for authOptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

For a session, I need to GET AND POST and in doc see code and work but my project doesn't work.
Import handler and see an error

```
import { authOptions } from "@/app/authapi/auth"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions as any)



export { handler as POST, handler as GET }
```

Error is like that

```
import {handler}  from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";



ERROR:

Module '"@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"' declares 'handler' locally, but it is exported as 'POST'.ts(2460)
route.ts(4, 7): 'handler' is declared here.
```

see an error in my vs code
it works and doesn't break my web
but when it is deployed, it returns an error

I tried and searched but didn't find any solution.

Comment: That module doesn't have an export named `handler`. It exports that local under a different name, hence the `export {handler as POST}`.